# How to design database to store and retrieve large item/skill lists in ruby

Tags: ruby, database-design

I plan a role playing game where characters are supposed to carry/use items and train skills. When it comes to store (possibly numerous) items/skills possessed by characters, I can't think of a better way than putting a row for every possible item and skill to each character instantiated. However this seems to be an overkill to me.

To be clear, if this would be an exercise or a small game where total number of items/skills is ~30, I would add an items and a skills hash to the character class and methods to add and remove them like:

```
def initialize
  @inventory = {}
  @skills = {}
end

def add_item item, number
  @inventory[item] += number
end
```

Regarding that I would like to store the number of the items and the levels of the skills, what else can I try to handle ~1000 items and ~150 in the inventory and possibly 100 skills?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Plan for Data Retrieval

Generally, it's a good idea to design your database around how you plan to look up and retrieve your data, rather than how you want to store it. A bad design makes your data very expensive to collect from the database.

In your example, having a separate model for each inventory item or skill would be hugely expensive in terms of lookups whenever you want to load a character. Do you really want to do 1,000 lookups every time you load someone's inventory? Probably not.

#### Denormalize for Speed

You typically want to normalize data that needs to be consistent, and denormalize data that needs to be retrieved/updated quickly. One option might be to [serialize your character attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize).

For example, it should be faster to store a serialized Character#inventory_items field than update 100 separate records with a `has_many :though` or `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship. There are certainly trade-offs involved with denormalization in general and serialization in particular, but it might be a good fit for your specific use case.

#### Consider a Document Database

Character sheets are documents. Unless you need the relational power of a SQL database, a document-oriented database might be a better fit for the data you want to manage. CouchDB seems particularly well-suited for this example, but you should certainly evaluate all your NoSQL options to see if any offer the features you need. Your mileage will definitely vary.

#### Always Benchmark

Don't take my word for what's optimal. Try a design. Benchmark it. See what the design does with *your* data. In the end, that's the only thing that matters.

Comment: You may want to mention the common hazards in using a NoSQL approach.

Comment: I liked CouchDB at first glance, especially after seeing a datamapper adapter for it. I don't plan to use Rails at this point but I guess I can incorporate 'serialize' functionality by using an array for skill levels only with predetermined indexes for each skill name. As for benchmarking however, I never did it before (I used MiniTest a lot but couldn't make use of its benchmarking methods). Could you very mind to point me to some guides for benchmarking ruby code?

Comment: @barerd "Where can I find..." questions are usually off-topic on Stack Overflow, but http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[ruby-on-rails]+benchmark is certainly a great place to start!

Answer (score 1):

> I can't think of a better way than putting a row for every possible item and skill to each character instantiated.

Do characters evolve independently?

- Assuming yes, there is no other choice but having each end every relevant combination physically represented in the database.
- If not, then you can "reuse" the same set or items/skills for multiple characters, but this is probably not what is going on here.

In any case, relational databases are very good at managing huge amounts of data and the numbers you mentioned don't even qualify as "huge". By correctly utilizing techniques such as [clustering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index), you can ensure that a lookup of all items/skills for a given character is done in a minimal number of I/O operations, i.e. very fast.